# Complex Query with related tables - Optimal Solution

Tags: mysql

## The Schema:

I have 3 Tables:

- User
- Feature
- User_has_Feature:

initially all users has no features

Example data:

User:

```
| id | name |
| 1  | Rex  |
| 2  | Job  |
```

Feature:

```
| id | name |
| 1  | Eat  |
| 2  | Walk |
```

User_has_Feature:

```
| id | user_id | feature_id | have_feature |
| 1  | 1       | 1          | true         |
| 2  | 1       | 1          | true         |
| 3  | 2       | 2          | true         |
| 4  | 2       | 2          | false        |
```

## The questions are:

- ¿How to get only the records that have all features? (**explicitly**)

Example:

```
| user_name | feature_name | feature_status |
| Rex       | Eat          | true           |
| Rex       | Walk         | true           |
```

- How to get records that do not have all the features? (again **explicitly**)

Example:

```
| user_name | feature_name | feature_status |
| Job       | Eat          | true           |
| Job       | Walk         | false          |
```

## Some conditions have to be attended

- I need the Users list with all features (true or false) in both queries **like examples**
- User have 650k records (for now)
- Feature have 45 records (for now)
- Is one time query.

The idea is to export the result to a CSV file

---

## Early Solution

thanks to the answers of (@RolandoMySQLDBA, @Tom Ingram, @DRapp) I found a solution:

```
SELECT u.name, f.name, IF(uhf.status=1,'YES','NO') as status
FROM user u
  JOIN user_has_feature uhf ON u.id = uhf.user_id
  JOIN feature f ON f.id = uhf.feature_id
  JOIN 
       (
         SELECT u.id as id
         FROM user u
           JOIN user_has_feature uhf ON uhf.user_id = u.id
         WHERE uhf.status = 1
         GROUP BY u.id
         HAVING count(u.id) <= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM feature)
       ) as `condition` ON `condition`.id = u.id
ORDER BY u.name, f.id, uhf.status
```

For get records that do not have all the features and for get all record that have all features change:

- `WHERE uhf.status = 1` by `WHERE uhf.status = 2`
- `HAVING count(u.id) <= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM feature)` by `HAVING count(u.id) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM feature)`

but I want to know if this is an **optimal solution**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    UNF.*,
    IF(
        (LENGTH(UNF.FeatureList) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UNF.FeatureList,',','')))
        = (FC.FeatureCount - 1),'Has All Features','Does Not Have All Features'
    ) HasAllFeatures
FROM
    (SELECT
        U.name user_name
        GROUP_CONCAT(F.name) Features
    FROM
        (SELECT user_id,feature_id FROM User_has_Feature
        WHERE feature_status = true) UHF
        INNER JOIN User U ON UHF.user_id = U.id
        INNER JOIN Feature F ON UHF.feature_id = F.id
    GROUP BY
       U.name
    ) UNF,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FeatureCount FROM Feature) FC
;
```

The UNF subquery returns with all users listed in User_has_Feature and a comma-separated list of the features. The column `HasAllFeatures` is determined by the number of columns in `UNF.FeatureList`. In your case, there are two features. If the number of commas in UNF.FeatureList is FeatureCount - 1, then the user has all features. Otherwise, user does not have all features.

Here is a better version that shows all users and whether or not they have all, some or no features

```
SELECT
    U.name user_name,
    IFNULL(UsersAndFeatures.HasAllFeatures,
    'Does Not Have Any Features')
    WhatFeaturesDoesThisUserHave
FROM
    User U LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            UHF.user_id id,
            IF(
                (LENGTH(UHF.FeatureList) - LENGTH(REPLACE(UHF.FeatureList,',','')))
                = (FC.FeatureCount - 1),
               'Has All Features',
               'Does Not Have All Features'
            ) HasAllFeatures
        FROM
            (
                SELECT user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(Feature.name) FeatureList
                FROM User_has_Feature INNER JOIN Feature
                ON User_has_Feature.feature_id = Feature.id
                GROUP BY user_id
            ) UHF,
            (SELECT COUNT(1) FeatureCount FROM Feature) FC
    ) UsersAndFeatures
USING (id);
```

Comment: The `UNF.FeatureList` from which comes

Comment: Sorry about UNF. The H and N are next to each other on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
      u.id,
      u.name as User_Name,
      f.name as Feature_Name,
      uhf.feature_Status
   from 
      ( select uhf.user_id, 
               sum( if( uhf.feature_status, 1, 0 ) ) as UserFeatureCount
           from user_has_feature uhf
           group by uhf.user_id ) AllUsersWithCounts

      join
      ( select count(*) as AllFeaturesCount
           from Feature ) AllFeatures
         on AllUsersWithCounts.UserFeatureCount = AllFeatures.AllFeaturesCount

      join user u
         on AllUsersWithCounts.user_id = u.ID

      join user_has_feature uhf
         on AllUsersWithCounts.User_id = uhf.user_id
         join feature f
            on uhf.feature_id = f.id
```

The above query should get all people that explicitly have ALL features.  In order to get those that do NOT have all features, just change the one join from = to <

```
 on AllUsersWithCounts.UserFeatureCount < AllFeatures.AllFeaturesCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bash at it

- create a view of the general information

  ```
  CREATE VIEW v_users_have_features AS
   SELECT usr.id, usr.name, feature.name, has_feature.status 
    FROM usr 
    JOIN has_feature ON usr.id = has_feature.user_id
    JOIN feature ON has_feature.feature_id = feature.id;
  ```
- use the view for other queries

  ```
  SELECT v_users_have_features.id, v_users_have_features.u_name, v_users_have_features.f_name
   FROM v_users_have_features
   GROUP BY v_users_have_features.id
   HAVING COUNT( v_users_have_features.id ) = (SELECT COUNT( feature.id ) 
                                                FROM feature
                                                WHERE feature.name = v_users_have_features.f_name )
  ```

p.s. you may need to adapt (particularly the latter) to your exact requirements you could also omit creating the view and nest it in the `FROM` clause like in another answer it just seemed handier to create the view

Comment: need not only the user "Rex" but all users who comply with the condition

Comment: `Feature` don't have a `user_id` field

Comment: qhen i try to execute the create view query. i get two errors "Subquery return more than 1 row"

Answer (score -1):

Count the number of features. Write a query over users that uses a correlated subquery to find all the features a user has and count them. Make the restriction criterion in the top query the equality of that count and the global number of features.

Can MySQL do correlated subqueries? If not, you might need to use a better database.